# W3C Extended Logging Format

Tags: oracle, weblogic, w3c

Anyone know if there were recent changes to the W3C Extended Logging Format options?  I recall "cs-username" being implemented, but I see no mention at http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html.

Here is an article describing implementation of cs-username;
http://middlewaretechnologies.blogspot.com/2012/03/configure-extended-logging-in-http.html

I also noticed a reference with IIS, but can not provide the URL since I do not have a reputation of 10 - google "IIS extended logging format w3c"

I am trying to implement the "cs-username" functionality within Weblogic 12c via extended logging format, but it may appear Oracle only provides a subset of the standards - yet this may not be the case since I see no mention of said field on w3c site.  Perplexed.  Writing a custom java class may be the only solution, but that is going to require a bit of research for me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The development of the [Extended Log File Format](https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-logfile.html) was discussed on a [dedicated mailing list at W3C](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-logging/Overview.html). The archives of that mailing list don't contain any messages after September 1996, and the last draft of the format dates from March 1996. (One of the last messages that was explicitly about the development of the format dates from [April 1996](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-logging/msg00095.html).

So I would say that the format was not developed further after 1996.